# Why is the mirror making secondary lines?

Tags: mesh

[image]

Why is the mirror modifier making secondary lines and how can i make this not happen its on origin to geometry bounds center the lines are only there when i have the mirror modifier on with x axis location of x is set to zero and i have no shape keys

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Use punctuation please. This "one-sentence" is quite hard to understand given that image doesn't explain well the original state of mesh and what modifier actually adds to it

Answer (score 1):

You need to provided a better image of your mesh that covers more detail. But my guess at this point is that your mesh is off center and the current transformation has not been applied.